# Use child's attribute in parent's constructor

Tags: java, parent-child, super

```
class abstract Parent ()
{
     private int a;
     private final int b = a + 1; // a is null at that point
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
       a = 2;
    }
}
```

That wouldn't really be a problem in C++ (because pointers), but I'm not sure how to handle this issue in Java. Obviously `a` is equal to 0 when `Parent` tries to initiate `b`.

I initially tried calling `super()` after setting `a`, but apparently `super()` has to be called first in `child`'s constructor. I don't want to set `b` in `Childs` and I'd prefer `b` to be `final` too. Any ideas?

Comment: You can assign to final variables in the constructor *as long as you haven't already assigned to them*.

Comment: Also, if super() has parameters you can inline the assignments there

Comment: @tibetiroka so i'd set a in parent's constructor by passing it as a parameter in super() ?

Comment: `a` is not `null`, it is `0` (zero).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my bad, i'm actually not using ints so I didn't think about that. I guess the default value for integer is 0 since it is primitive.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Badda That is the general approach

Comment: @tibetiroka I thought abstract classes could not have a constructor, and final attributes could not be initiated in constructor too. So I was miles away from doing that. Thanks !

Comment: Every final variable is initialized in the constructor. If you write it at the declaration or in a code block the compiler moves it to the constructor, right after the super() call, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want cannot be done like this, what you need to do is pass the value of `a` to a constructor of `Parent`:

```java
abstract class Parent {
    private int a;
    private final int b;

    protected Parent(int a) {
        this.a = a;
        b = a + 1;
    }
}
```

And define `Child` as:

```java
class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        super(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works and even allows `a` to be final too. Thanks.